# Clustering individuals with random observations

Tags: machine-learning, r, clustering

I'm currently trying to apply clustering algorithm to data on callcenter employee KPIs. My dataset contains daily observations per employee on 3 KPIs. Yet the challenge is that I have a random number of observations per employee and at random intervals, as not every employee works every day. I would like to use the same approach as described [Cadez, Gaffney & Smith (2000)](http://ftp.cse.buffalo.edu/users/azhang/disc/disc01/cd1/out/papers/kdd/p140-cadez.pdf) and I am trying to find a package in R that could help me do that. Popular EM cluster packages such as Mclust do not allow to specify which observation belongs to which individual (as far as I know). Does anyone know of an R implementation for such an algorithm? I've added a small example of my data below.

```
ID  Date   KPI1  KPI2  KPI3
1   1/1    1.2    1.3  2.0
2   2/1    1.4    1    2.2
1   2/1    1.2    1    2.5
2   2/1    1.4    1.2  2.4
1   3/1    1.2    1    2.3
3   3/1    1.5    1.3  2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

How random is the distribution? You could "smooth" the problem away by taking daily, weekly, or monthly averages of those KPIs per employee and clustering on *that*.

Comment: That is of course possible, but that is just not the approach I (preferably) want to take. Hence my question if there is an R package that supports the method of the Cadez et al. paper.